# Value of $\sum_{j=1} (y_{j} - \bar{y})$ and proving properties of hat value

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear, sum

The i-th fitted value $\hat{Z}_i$ is written as a linear amalgam of response values $\hat{Z}_i=\sum_{j=1}h_{ij}Z_j$ where $h_{ij}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}}$ and $S_{yy}=\sum_{i=1}(y_i-\bar{y})^2$.

I am trying to show $\sum_{j=1}h_{ij}^2=h_{ii}$ and $\sum_{j=1}h_{ij}y_j=y_i$; however, I am already stuck on the first one after doing the following.

$$
\begin{align}
h_{ij}^2 &= \Bigg[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}}\Bigg]^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n}\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}}+\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})^2(y_j-\bar{y})^2}{S_{yy}^2} \\
&= \frac{S_{yy}^2}{n^2S_{yy}^2}+
\frac{2n}{n^2}\frac{S_{yy}(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}^2}
+\frac{n^2(y_i-\bar{y})^2(y_j-\bar{y})^2}{n^2S_{yy}^2} \\
&=\frac{S_{yy}^2+2nS_{yy}(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})+n^2(y_i-\bar{y})^2(y_j-\bar{y})^2}{n^2S_{yy}^2} \\
&=\frac{\big[S_{yy}+n(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})\big]^2}{n^2S_{yy}^2}
\end{align}
$$
I don't see how applying the summation $\sum_{j=1}$ to this leads to $h_{ii}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}{S_{yy}}$. Am I missing something about what can be assumed or what is already known about $\sum_{j=1}(y_j-\bar{y})$ and $\sum_{j=1}(y_j-\bar{y})^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on your second line. First term:
$$\sum_j\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$
Second term:
$$\sum_j\frac{2}{n}\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})(y_j-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}^2}=\frac{2(y_i-\bar{y})}{nS_{yy}^2}\sum_j(y_j-\bar{y})=0$$
Third term:
$$\sum_j\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})^2(y_j-\bar{y})^2}{S_{yy}^2}=\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}{S_{yy}^2}\underbrace{\sum_j (y_j-\bar{y})^2}_{S_{yy}}=\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}{S_{yy}}$$
When summed, the three terms give you $h_{ii}$.

Comment: Thanks, I have a bad habit of losing the forest from the trees so I apologize for the silly question.

Comment: @strwars you're welcome. It's not a silly one at all, you've asked your question the way it should be, i.e. by sharing your progress.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind I'm having a similar issue with proving $\sum_{j=1}h_{ij}y_j=y_i$. I have simplified the equation all the way to $\sum_{j=1}h_{ij}y_j=\bar{y}+\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})}{S_{yy}}\Bigg[\sum_{j=1}(y_j^2-\bar{y}^2)\Bigg]$, but cannot proceed further. It looks like I need $\sum_{j=1}(y_j^2-\bar{y}^2)=S_{yy}$, but I don't think I can make this happen. I tried introducing $2y_j\bar{x}-2y_j\bar{y}$ within the summation, but that gives me a $2\bar{y}^2n$ term I cannot seem to get rid of.

Comment: @strwars it’s best if you could post it as a separate question and share how you reached the final formula you have since it might be quite long for a comment (and maybe others can also help)